# How to check a folder exists in DropBox using DropNet

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet

I'm programming an app that interact with dropbox by use DropNet API. I want to check if the folder is exist or not on dropbox in order to I will create one and upload file on it after that. Everything seen fine but if my folder is exist it throw exception. Like this:

```
if (isAccessToken)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    try
    {
        string dropboxFolder = "/Public/DropboxManagement/Logs" + folder;

        // I want to check if the dropboxFolder is exist here

        _client.CreateFolder(dropboxFolder); 

        var upload = _client.UploadFile(dropboxFolder, fileName, bytes);
    }
    catch (DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Response.Content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with dropnet, but looking at the source code, it appears you should be able to do this by using the [`GetMetaData()`](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Client/Files.Sync.cs) method off of your `_client` object. This method returns a [`MetaData`](https://github.com/dkarzon/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Models/MetaData.cs) object.

Example:

```
//gets contents at requested path
var metaData = _client.GetMetaData("/Public/DropboxManagement/Logs");
//without knowing how this API works, Path may be a full path and therefore need to check for "/Public/DropboxManagement/Logs" + folder
if (metaData.Contents.Any(c => c.Is_Dir && c.Path == folder)
{
     //folder exists
}
```

Comment: By the way, you probably don't need to create the folder at all. Folders are created implicitly when you write a file in Dropbox. (So if you write a file `/Public/DropboxManagement/Logs/hello.txt`, the folder `/Public/DropboxManagement/Logs` will be created if necessary.)